# Multible for loops depending on each other in a more pythonic way

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, list-comprehension

Dear Stackoverflowers,

I wrote a working loop in a loop which goes through ndarrays within a list. I was wondering if there is a more elegant "pythonisch" solution.

If there is a solution with list comprehension, could you explain it step by step so I can follow and learn? I tried it but the for loop depending on a for loop did not work for me.

- I have a list *y_labeled* where each list element *i* is an ndarray of *j* elements.
- I have a *dict* with different weight values. The keys of the values can be found in *y_labeled*. *y_labeled* also contains a masking value 0 
  [Here I tried to set the get(key,default=0) but that created an error so I used the if].

Now I loop through each *y_labeled* list element-> through each array element and save the corresponding weight in a new list *weight* made again of ndarrays.

The aim is to create another list such as *y_labeled* containing the corresponding weight values (you may have guessed it -> its sample_weigth).

```
   weigth=list();tmp2=[]
   for i in range(len(y_labeled)):
          for j in range(len(y_labeled[i])):               
                 for k in (y_labeled[i][j]):
                        if k !=0:
                               tmp=weights_dict.get(y_labeled[i].item(np.asscalar(k)))
                        else:
                               tmp=0                                                                           
                        tmp2.append(tmp)
          weigth.append(tmp2); tmp=[];tmp2=[]
```

Thank you very much

Edit: 
some example data:

```
y_labeled=list([1,2,2,4,4,1,1],[2,1,1,4,4,0,0],[2,2,2,2,0,0,0])

weights_dict={1:5, 2:6, 4:19}
```

result:

```
weight=list([5,6,6,19,19,5,5],[6,5,5,19,19,0,0],[6,6,6,6,0,0,0])
```

Comment: Please see the edit of the main post. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll have a look, the only thing I can say right away is that looping on the element of an array is extremely inefficient. The interest of numpy is that you can do operation array-wide.

Comment: Dear Mathieu, I thought so. Comming form years of Matlab, my brain is still wired the " wrong" way. The intention of the whole post is a bit to rewire my brain :-) Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail... I mean the code above can't even work... `tmp2`? When do you initialize `weight`? And when you say: " each list element i is an ndarray of j elements.", what is the shape of the ndarray? Is it a 1D ?

Comment: Oh dear, sorry. just call tmp2=[] before the loop, same for weight=list(). I will edit this right away

Comment: No problem, but it's just a bit hard to get what is the input, what is the output, and what you need to perform to get it.

Comment: The input ndarrays are 1D arrays. Of course, it would also be interesting for nD arrays as I have this case also often. But for now this is just 1D. The input list/arrays are labels for  other data. I want to create a sample_weigth list in the same form as the target data (y_labeled) with the sample_weights as values. The sample_weight values are stored in the dict for each label (key).

Comment: More and more confusing. If it's 1D, your code can't work. `for k in blabla` blabla is an integer.

Comment: Sorry, I jsut noticed that (x,1) counts as 2D array. So all my ndarray list elements are actually 2D. Can the .flatten() be integrated in the list comprehension? Sorry for all the confusion.

Comment: That (x,1) is not 1D is very confusing for a " python-foreigner" :-) I learn every day. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using nested [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> y_labeled = [[1,2,2,4,4,1,1], [2,1,1,4,4,0,0], [2,2,2,2,0,0,0]]
>>> weights_dict = {1:5, 2:6, 4:19}
>>> [[weights_dict.get(x, 0) for x in sublist] for sublist in y_labeled]
[[5, 6, 6, 19, 19, 5, 5], [6, 5, 5, 19, 19, 0, 0], [6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Dear Vincent that looks very clean thanks. coff coff, I get an error as I actually have a 2D array for each list element (x,1) instead of (x,). Sorry. Where would I have to apply the .flatten()?

Comment: `y_labeled = [elt.flatten() for elt in y_labeled]` should probably work? Or `for x in sublist.flatten()`

Comment: Dear Mathieu, and Vincent [[weights_dict.get(x, 0) for x in sublist.flatten()] for sublist in y_labeled] did the job. You are the best. P.s. Mathieu, your answer from above works as well like a charm

Answer (score 1):

A solution using indexing with `numpy` arrays:

```
import numpy as np
y_labeled=[np.array([1,2,2,4,4,1,1]),
           np.array([2,1,1,4,4,0,0]),
           np.array([2,2,2,2,0,0,0])]

# Convert dictionary to numpy array
weights_dict={1:5, 2:6, 4:19}
weight_vector = np.zeros(max(weights_dict.keys()) + 1)
for k, v in weights_dict.items():
    weight_vector[k] = v

print("Weight vector")
print(weight_vector)


# use y_labeled to select the coefficients of weight_matrix
weight = [weight_vector[y] for y in y_labeled]

print("Output weight")
for w in weight:
    print(w)
```

Output:

```
Weight vector
[ 0.  5.  6.  0. 19.]
Output weight
[ 5.  6.  6. 19. 19.  5.  5.]
[ 6.  5.  5. 19. 19.  0.  0.]
[6. 6. 6. 6. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: Dear mcoav thanks for your contribution. Maybe I stated that to unclear. the input is vice versa: y_labeled list(array([...]),array([...])). So each List element of y_labeled is an 1D array.

Answer (score 1):

Finally understood the topic....
Here is a solution using numpy and working with NDarrays.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import numpy as np

y_labeled = [np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 10, size = (5, 2)),
             np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 10, size = (5, 2)),
             np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 10, size = (5, 2))]

weights = np.random.randint(low = 0, high = 10, size = (10, ))
weights_dict = {i:weights[i] for i in range(10)}

results = list()
for y_mat in y_labeled:
    weight_matrix = np.zeros(shape = y_mat.shape)
    for i in range(10):
        weight_matrix[y_mat == i] = weights_dict[i]

    results.append(weight_matrix)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I choose Vincents as the final answer as it is even more pythonic with the one line solution. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: @FloridaMan You could test both with %timeit aswell. The asset of this one is that it works with NDarray (whatever size and dimension) and that it uses numpy which is coded in C... and much faster than list comprehension. The answer for Vincent is great for 1D and probably faster for 1D.

Comment: Thanks you for clarifying. I will definitely reuse your code as I run multiple times into this problem with NDarryas N>1. Thanks so much for the more generic code.